# Virtualbox will not start after upgrading to 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I am trying to run virtualbox. It worked fine last time I used it a month or two back but I have upgraded to 10 since then and now it flashes in task manager for half a second and vanishes. I updated to the latest and still get the same thing. I also tried disabling Hyper-V and restarted and still get nothing.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [official download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads):

> Please be aware that Windows 10 is not yet officially supported! There are known problems with VirtualBox 5.0 on Windows 10 hosts and with Windows 10 guests. Some of the problems are fixed in the most recent test build which can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem. Updated to latest stable version 5.1.4 and all is working now!